# Google play games.Turn based Bug or feature?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I ve tried to ask the same question on github at the official unity google play games plugin but i dont see any answers.So i hope i ll find more ideas here.
I use google play games plugin for unity from their official github page and i run the Tic Tac Toe sample.It is a turn based game for Android-Ios devices.
 From what i see the gameplay is like:

player connects to google tries to hit the desired square with his ball and when the ball stops moving the turn is passed to the next player.The next player accept the challenge and the turn based game continues...

My Question is really simple. When the player tries to hit the desired square with his ball if he fails he can simply press the home button just before the google sends the turn to the other player,go to google play games and accept his turn again.Now he can make his move all over again until he hits the desired block.

Google play game services are live one and a half year now.How noone reported this?Am i doing something wrong?Is there anyone out there using this plugin or am i alone :P ?

Comment: The only solution that comes to my mind is 
when OnApplicaitonPause(true) is called on unity, give instantly the turn to the next player.But noone will be happy if they get a call or a message and lose their turn.

Answer (score 1):

Umm. let's call it a feature :) .  Seriously, there is a lot of moving parts between accepting the invitation and taking a turn.  It would be very tricky to do this consistently given network connections that come and go in the mobile environment and not lose a turn or end up with what you described.

I think there are a couple of options:

1. Allow a "[mulligan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulligan_(games))".  Sure, there maybe some players that just keep trying, but overall, the game will probably be more fun.
2. Save the game state using [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) to an "autosaved" file.  Then always load it when starting.  This way even if TakeTurn() is not called, they will come back to the game as they left it.  Using Saved Games also has the advantage of working across devices, so they can't just switch devices and play again to bypass any local state.

Comment: Ok number 2 sounds like a good solution.Interesting.I am going to try this.

Comment: Saving the game every one move will be very lagy.Players fire 5 shots in 10 seconds at their turn.The only solution i can think of, is to create a service and use it us a plugin to my unity game that saves the game only when it comes to background?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution for this issue that you can try is to

```
Application.runinBackground = false"
```

Hope this Helps!!